# Amalgamated product of join of spaces is trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ three different path connected spaces. Show
>   that the amalgamted product of $\pi(X \star Y_1, x_o)$ $\star_{\pi(X,
>  x_o)}$ $\pi(X \star Y_2, x_o)$ is the trivial fundamental group.

Where $X\star Y_1$ is the join, i.e, the quotient space of $X \times Y_1 \times [0,1]$ under the indetifications $(x,y_1,0) \sim (x,y_2,0)$ and $(x_1,y,1) \sim (x_2,y,1)$

How can I start to show it?

Comment: You should explain what you know already about this problem, what you have tried, where you got stuck, and so on. Otherwise, your answerers may well waste time explaining things that you already know without every getting to the point of what you don't know.

Comment: Sorry for that. So I know how to use the amalgmated product for concrete spaces, such as spheres or torus, but I do not know how to use it in general. I know the definition, but since I have no idea about how the fundamental groups of these spaces are, I do not know how to start. So I would need a hint or something to start the exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few hints to get you started.

---

- The group in question is the fundamental group of $X\star Y_1$ glued to $X\star Y_2$ along their $X$ faces.

---

- For any pair of spaces $A$ and $B$, note that given a loop $\gamma:S^1\to A\star B$ where $\theta\mapsto (a_{\theta}, b_{\theta}, t_{\theta})$, you can perform the homotopy

$$\gamma_s(\theta) = (a_{\theta}, b_{\theta}, t_{\theta} + (s-1)t_{\theta}).$$

Think about the identifications, and what this homotopy does to the loop in question.

---

Comment: I see in some way that if $a_{\theta}$ and $b_{\theta}$ are fixed, by moving the third coordinate between 0 and 1, we get a loop and in some way through the identifications, everything is the same point so it would be a constant loop. So I think I see the idea, but would you mind clarifying the notation?

Comment: The idea is that $a_{\theta}$ is the $A$-coordinate of the loop gamma at the point $\theta$ along $S^1$, and similarly for $b_{\theta}$. So, if $a_{\theta}$ and $b_{\theta}$ are fixed for all $\theta$, then you already have the constant loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!